# VB.NET - XMLSerialization - Adding Type attribute of 'Array' to root node of Array

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization

I have the below setup to Classes to create some XML using Serialization using vb.net.

```
Public Class USER
    Public Property USERCODE As String
    Public Property COMPANYCODE As String
    Public Property LEDGERCODE As String
    Public Property WORKGROUP As String
    Public Property SYSTEMDATE As Date
End Class

Public Class JOB
    Private myItems() As Object
    Public Property USER As New SchedulerParameters.USER
    Public Property [OBJECT] As String
    Public Property METHOD As String

    <XmlArrayItem(ElementName:="PARAMETER"), XmlArray()>
    Public Property PARAMETERS As Object()
        Get

            Return myItems
        End Get
        Set
            myItems = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Which creates

```
<JOB xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">    
<USER>      
    <USERCODE>RW</USERCODE>      
    <COMPANYCODE>DEM</COMPANYCODE>      
    <LEDGERCODE>PL1</LEDGERCODE>      
    <WORKGROUP>DIRECTOR</WORKGROUP>      
    <SYSTEMDATE>0001-01-01T00:00:00</SYSTEMDATE>    
</USER>    
<OBJECT>QLHSGPostingRoutines.HPM.OrderStatusChange</OBJECT>    
<METHOD>Issue</METHOD>    
<PARAMETERS>
    <PARAMETER xsi:type="xsd:string">66827</PARAMETER>
    <PARAMETER xsi:type="xsd:string">NULL</PARAMETER>
</PARAMETERS>
</JOB>
```

I would like to have the attribute on PARAMETERS:

```
<PARAMETERS type="Array">
```

For calling I use:

```
    .....
    _xml.PARAMETERS = _paramArray

    Dim xs As New XmlSerializer(_xml.GetType)

    xs.Serialize(_s, _xml)

    Return _s.ToString
```

I was hoping to use  but this does not work for some reason.

If someone could help me out that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you want you *cannot* use a simple array like that, you *have* to create some sort of object/POCO for it.

```
Public Class JOB
    Public Property USER As New SchedulerParameters.USER
    Public Property [OBJECT] As String
    Public Property METHOD As String

    Public Property PARAMETERS As PARAMETERS
End Class

Public Class PARAMETERS
    <XmlAttribute("type")>
    Public Property Type As String = "Array"

    <XmlElement("PARAMETER")>
    Public Property Items As Object()
End Class
```

By creating a class, and then specifying `XmlElement("PARAMETER")` and `XmlAttribute("type")` on the string, it will generate the XML you want:

```
  <PARAMETERS type="Array">
    <PARAMETER xsi:type="xsd:string">66827</PARAMETER>
    <PARAMETER xsi:type="xsd:string">NULL</PARAMETER>
  </PARAMETERS>
```

I'm not sure *why* you want this format, if you are using .NET to serialize and deserialize it then you *don't* need the extra `type` attribute.

Comment: Same old story of maintaining Legacy systems while adding new functionality. Thanks, I'll give it a go in a moment and let you know how it goes.

Comment: As a follow on - as I am here, how do i remove

xsi:type="xsd:string"

From the parameter nodes?

Comment: @RhysWilliams The only *simple* way to do that is to change the `Items` property from an `Object()` to a `String()`.